# How to get a componenet instance in React

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to know if there is possible to get the component instance as I need.

I put my new component as a children in the main state, but is no the same object in both files.

I need to reach children state in my MainComponent. Looking in google for componenet instance doesnt help, maybe I am out of focus and the name of this is different.

Here is my MainComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AnotherComponent from './../whatever/AnotherComponent';

class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     children: [],
    };
  }

  addChild() {
   const { children } = this.state;
   this.setState({
    children: children.push(<AnotherComponent />)
   });
  }

  getChildrenState(component) {
    return component.state(); // this doesn't work!
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.state;
    return ( 
     <div>
       {(children.map(i => (<div key={this.getChildrenState(i).id}>{i}</div>))}
     </div>
    )
  }
```

And This is AnotherComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AnotherComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     id: 144,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
     <div>
       Here it is my cHild!
     </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `<AnotherComponent/>` to the state doesn't make sense because it's React element object that isn't associated with specific component instance.

Accessing children state in parent component breaks the encapsulation and indicates design problem.

The instance of class component should be retrieved with a ref, and doing so to access instance `state` is the last resort that may be needed to extend third-party components that don't provide desired functionality.

If `AnotherComponent` is first-party component, it should be designed accordingly, to not require `state` to be accessed from the outside:

```
  render() {
    return ( 
     <div key={this.state.id}>{this.state.id}</div>
    )
  }
```

If the output needs to be more flexible, it can make use of render prop pattern:

```
  render() {
    const render = React.Children.only(children);
    return ( 
     <div key={this.state.id}>{render(this.state.id)}</div>
    )
  }
```

And used like:

```
<AnotherComponent>{id => <div>{id}</div>}</AnotherComponent>
```

Comment: Really need to take control of my children state. But maybe I need to change my design, I Will play a little bit with something of your response and then let you know if works! Thx

Comment: *But maybe I need to change my design* - yes, this was the point. Hope this helps.

Comment: I Change my design to handleStateChange trigger a prop method passed.
Thx for this, Your response is better explained. This is why is checked as correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the state of the child component ( here `AnotherComponent` ) then you can either :

- Maintain the state inside the `AnotherComponent` and pass the value to the parent ( here `MainComponent` ) on a change listener ( whenever the state changes ), or;
- Maintain the state in the parent ( here `MainComponent` ) and pass the value to the child as prop.

Let me know if you want me to give an example implementation.

Comment: There will be a lot of children and also children in children. I dont wanna to make listeners everywhere but maybe a quick method by props returning his children state works!.

I let you know after playing with this Works! THX!